# Error updating Meteor project from 1.5.2.2 to 1.6

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I'm trying to update a meteor project but having some issues.

I'm using MacOS High Sierra v10.13.2

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling fourseven:scss
- Updating NPM
- `npm rebuild`
- `npm rebuild --update-binary`
- delete `node_modules` and `meteor npm install`

Here is my error:

```
Seans-MBP:calendar sean$ meteor update
=> Errors while initializing project:

While loading package fourseven:scss@3.13.0:
error: Command failed:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node',
gyp verb cli
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@8.9.3 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15) code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir compiling against specified --nodedir dev files:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
line tools instance

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
gyp ERR! command
"/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
"rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sean/.npm/_logs/2018-01-10T02_03_21_566Z-debug.log
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node',
gyp verb cli
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.4.0
gyp info using node@8.9.3 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15) code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir compiling against specified --nodedir dev files:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created?
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file:
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args
'/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args
'-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
line tools instance

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit
(/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.3.0
gyp ERR! command
"/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.1vvxo4o.3yat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
"rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd
/Users/sean/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.3.13.0.1gz1gxy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScssBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScssBatch/node_modules/.temp-1tvdw0j.iybsl/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/sean/.npm/_logs/2018-01-10T02_03_21_566Z-debug.log
```

Any help much appreciated!!!

Comment: copied my answer over from the meteor forums for the points

Comment: @FredStark thanks for your time. I'll delete the one on Meteor forums and give you the points here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial line in the error logs is this one:

```
xcode-select: error: tool ‘xcodebuild’ requires Xcode, but active developer directory ‘/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools’ is a command line tools instance
```

As it says, compiling node-sass requires a full Xcode install

Yeah, it sucks. node-sass has a few weird things like this that always get people, but the improvement over using the ruby version is worth it

Comment: Worked perfectly. Really appreciate the help!